# C++ Shell in Unix, execv: Dynamically create and Return a usable second parameter from a function

Tags: c++, shell, unix, execv

Everywhere I've looked for answers to this question, I see people making one small char * array of size like two and hardcoding in paths for execv. What I need to do is to take a string of parameters with the path as the first set of characters, tokenize them, and then put them in an array of char *s that execv will accept.

here is my tokenization function

```
char ** stringToVectorToCharArray(string inputString)
{
stringstream ss(inputString);
cout << "\n inputString is: " << inputString <<"\n";
vector<string> tokens;
tokens.clear();

while(ss >> inputString)
{
    tokens.push_back(inputString);
    }


int size = tokens.size();       
char **args = new char*[size + 1];

int i = 0;
for(; i < size; i++)
    args[i] = const_cast<char *>(tokens.at(i).c_str());

args[i + 1] = (char *) 0;

return args;
}
```

And this is called from

```
 char **args = stringToVectorToCharArray(inputString);

 execv(executeChar, args);
```

Within the Child section of my fork() if-else statements for flow control.
I get a bad_alloc error, but I'm not sure which of my allocation statements are right, if any are for that matter. I know the return has to be in the form

```
 char *const argv[]
```

But I'm not sure how to set that up.

Comment: The `execv` function will *not* throw an exception, it's incapable of it being a C function. You need to run in a debugger to actually catch the exception, or let the system create a core dump that you can use.

Comment: Also, doing `const_cast` is in most cases a sign you're doing something you should not, it's a code smell.

Comment: The only thing in the code above that could be throwing an exception would be the `stringToVectorToCharArray` call, but since you don't include the code for this or what `inputString` is, it's impossible to answer your question. Try to create a small self-contained example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning memory from a local variable (`tokens`) from your function.

```
for(; i < size; i++) {
  // stores pointer to local memory: args[i] = const_cast<char *>(tokens.at(i).c_str());
  args[i] = new char[tokens.at(i).size()+1];  // Create dynamically allocated copy
  strcpy(args[i], tokens.at(i).c_str());
}
```

The above should fix the problem. Technically, this would create a memory leak, since the memory is never deallocated, but your call to `execv` will replace your executable and effectively deallocate the memory.